# How to adjust column width of columns created with colspan

Tags: html, css

I would like to have control of the width of the two TH columns identified by the class class="ctrl-EASI"  and class="ctrl-solution".  At the moment they are embedded withing the class 'target-state' and are distributed evenely at 50% / 50%.   I would like the width of the first column to be 30% and the second to be 70%.

```css
.target-state{
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #f1f8ff;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
     <thead class="ctrl-rpt-header">
            <tr><th rowspan="2" class="ctrl-name">Control Name</th><th rowspan="2" class="ctrl-description">Description</th><th rowspan="2" class="ctrl-risks">Risks</th><th colspan="2" class="target-state">TARGET STATE</th><th colspan="4" class="ctrl-benefits">Benefits</th></tr>
            <tr class="second-row-ctrl-rpt"><th class="ctrl-EASI">EASI</th><th class="ctrl-solution">Proposed Solution</th><th class="ctrl-risk">Risk Reduction</th><th class="ctrl-client-svc">Client Svc</th><th class="ctrl-efficiency">Efficiency</th><th class="ctrl-competitive-advantage ">Competitive Adv</th></tr>

        </thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the two `th` elements underneath to take a percentage width, you assign the width by their class name:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwu5L9jt/) (added blue background to make it visibly obvious)

```
.ctrl-EASI {
  width: 30%;
}
.ctrl-solution {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assign width to your TH, either this way

```
<th style="width:30%" class="ctrl-EASI">EASI</th><th style="width:70%" class="ctrl-solution">Proposed Solution</th>
```

or you can assign width in your style class

```
 .ctrl-EASI {
 width: 30%;
}
.ctrl-solution {
width: 70%;
}
```